# Show day name instead of number from Open Weather API response

Tags: javascript, json, openweathermap

I am playing with [Open Weather API](https://openweathermap.org/) and managed to show 3 days weather, but I don't know how to show day instead of that number count!

After doing some search I found that I have to convert something like timestamp to normal time :/ but I am not able to understand.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var key = "16c772c85cc7406ce72731159d78b31b";
  var city = "Pune,IN";
  var url = "https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast";
  $.ajax({
    url: url, //API Call
    dataType: "json",
    type: "GET",
    data: {
      q: city,
      appid: key,
      units: "metric",
      cnt: "3"
    },
    success: function(data) {
      console.log('Received data:', data) // For testing
      var wf = "";
      wf += "<h2>" + data.city.name + "</h2>"; // City (displays once)
      $.each(data.list, function(index, val) {
        wf += "<p>" // Opening paragraph tag
        wf += "<b>Day " + index + "</b>: " // Day
        wf += val.main.temp + "&degC" // Temperature
        wf += "<span> " + val.weather[0].description + "</span>"; // Description
        wf += "<img src='https://openweathermap.org/img/w/" + val.weather[0].icon + ".png'>" // Icon
        wf += "</p>" // Closing paragraph tag
      });
      $("#showWeatherForcast").html(wf);
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="showWeatherForcast"></div>
```

Thank You

Comment: post reading the comments on answers. You're not putting any effort to solve or read the API document.

Comment: Sorry I am solving this now

Answer (score 3):

You can access the day from the timestamp in response. Define your day names (in English for example), convert the timestamp to `new Date` (multiply by 1000 to get the correct date) and get the day using native method.

```
var days = ['Sunday', 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday'];
var d = new Date(data.list[0].dt * 1000);
var dayName = days[d.getDay()];
console.log(dayName)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var key = "16c772c85cc7406ce72731159d78b31b";
        var city = "Pune,IN";
        var url = "https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast";
        $.ajax({
            url: url, //API Call
            dataType: "json",
            type: "GET",
            data: {
                q: city,
                appid: key,
                units: "metric",
                cnt: "17"
            },
            success: function(data) {
                const days = ['Sunday', 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday'];
                const timesToDisplay = [0, 8, 16];
                let d;
                let dayName;
                var wf = "";
                wf += "<h2>" + data.city.name + "</h2>"; // City (displays once)
                $.each(data.list, function(index, val) {
                  if(timesToDisplay.includes(index)){
                    d = new Date(data.list[index].dt * 1000);
                    dayName = days[d.getDay()];
                    wf += "<p>" // Opening paragraph tag
                    wf += "<b>Day " + timesToDisplay.indexOf(index) + " (" + dayName + ")</b>: " // Day
                    wf += val.main.temp + "&degC" // Temperature
                    wf += "<span> " + val.weather[0].description + "</span>"; // Description
                    wf += "<img src='https://openweathermap.org/img/w/" + val.weather[0].icon + ".png'>" // Icon
                    wf += "</p>" // Closing paragraph tag
                  }
                });
                $("#showWeatherForcast").html(wf);
            }
        });
    });
</script>
<p id="showWeatherForcast"></p>
```

Comment: Hi, Thank you but how can I implement this in my code. PS: I am a Learner

Comment: The updated code is showing Friday for all three days :/

Comment: API returns following timestamps: `1557468000, 1557478800, 1557489600`, which are all today (3 hours apart from eachother). You can use [timestamp converter](https://www.epochconverter.com/) to check what date they show (remember to multiply with `1000` to get milliseconds).

Comment: Thank You, I checked :/ Can you please tell me how can I show 3 days forecast?

Comment: That goes off topic, but you need to change your API call probably. I have not used this API.

Comment: So you are currently limiting the response to 3 lines with `cnt: "3"`. Since the API returns weather for every 3 hours, you should use `cnt: "24"` to get 72 hours forecast. If you strictly need 3 days not 72 hours you will have to calculate how many hours are left in today and adjust `cnt` accordingly.

Comment: When I put 24 it shows the 24 weather reports of 3 -3 hours of the gap, Link of API is https://openweathermap.org/forecast5

Comment: If you need one report per day you have to filter the results to get for example results `[1, 9, 17]`

Answer (score 1):

The response of the API contains the DateTime as timestamp. So you can use that timestamp to render the UI.

```
wf += "<b>DateTime " + new Date(val.dt*1000).toISOString() + "</b>: "
```

in response JSON, you've a list and inside each object they are passing the timestamp. To convert that time to human readable, you can multiple by 1000(milliseconds) and use the `DateTime` constructor to convert.

Once you have extracted the date, rest is a cake walk. (-_-)

Day extraction process

```
var allDays= ['Sunday', 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday'];
var d = new Date(data.list[0].dt * 1000); // to get the DateTime. 
var dayName = allDays[d.getDay()]; // It will give day index, and based on index we can get day name from the array. 
console.log(dayName)
```

Hope this helps.

```js
 $(document).ready(function() {
        var key = "16c772c85cc7406ce72731159d78b31b";
        var city = "Pune,IN";
        var url = "https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast";
        $.ajax({
            url: url, //API Call
            dataType: "json",
            type: "GET",
            data: {
                q: city,
                appid: key,
                units: "metric",
                cnt: "3"
            },
            success: function(data) {
                console.log('Received data:', data) // For testing
                
                var wf = "";
                wf += "<h2>" + data.city.name + "</h2>"; // City (displays once)
                $.each(data.list, function(index, val) {
                    wf += "<p>" // Opening paragraph tag
                    wf += "<b>Day " + index + "</b>: " // Day
                    wf += "<b>DateTime " + new Date(val.dt*1000).toISOString() + "</b>: " // DateTime
                    wf += val.main.temp + "&degC" // Temperature
                    wf += "<span> " + val.weather[0].description + "</span>"; // Description
                    wf += "<img src='https://openweathermap.org/img/w/" + val.weather[0].icon + ".png'>" // Icon
                    wf += "</p>" // Closing paragraph tag
                });
                $("#showWeatherForcast").html(wf);
            }
        });
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="showWeatherForcast"></div>
```

Comment: Hi there, Thank you but I want to show Day, not date!

Comment: @naveenkharwar updated the answer to get the exact day name.

Answer (score 1):

You can find the day from timestamp using the below snippet.

```
const weekDay = new Date(val.dt * 1000).toLocaleString("en-us", {
    weekday: "long"
});
```

The `new Date` constructor expects the timestamp in milliseconds but the API returns timestamp in seconds which is why a `* 1000` is required.

See the full implementation below.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var key = "16c772c85cc7406ce72731159d78b31b";
  var city = "Pune,IN";
  var url = "https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast";
  $.ajax({
    url: url, //API Call
    dataType: "json",
    type: "GET",
    data: {
      q: city,
      appid: key,
      units: "metric",
      cnt: "3"
    },
    success: function(data) {
      console.log('Received data:', data) // For testing
      var wf = "";
      wf += "<h2>" + data.city.name + "</h2>"; // City (displays once)
      $.each(data.list, function(index, val) {
        const weekDay = new Date(val.dt * 1000).toLocaleString("en-us", {
          weekday: "long"
        });
        wf += "<p>" // Opening paragraph tag
        wf += "<b>Day " + index + " (" + weekDay + ")" + "</b>: " // Day
        wf += val.main.temp + "&degC" // Temperature
        wf += "<span> " + val.weather[0].description + "</span>"; // Description
        wf += "<img src='https://openweathermap.org/img/w/" + val.weather[0].icon + ".png'>" // Icon
        wf += "</p>" // Closing paragraph tag
      });
      $("#showWeatherForcast").html(wf);
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="showWeatherForcast"></div>
```

Comment: Hey Thank You for your help your code is working perfect, but there is some problem in the API Call, have you ever worked with this API? Actually the API is not showing weather of each day :(

Comment: The ```cnt: "3"``` parameter indicates the first three results and not result for 3 days. For finding results for each day, you will have to get all results and then pick only entries from each day. Try asking that as a separate question.